# SQL Server query will not run with certain date range

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that will run for a time period of 01/07/13 - 01/13/13 but will not run for 01/14/13 - 01/20/13. The only differences are the dates. When I get the estimated execution plan for the non running date range it says I have a missing Index. When I add the index it runs fine. However I dont understand why this has happened out of the blue as this query runs in the back end of our app weekly. I will attach the 2 estimated Execution Plans.

Estimated Execution plans here:

1. Running https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8360/8362357080_0c1bb4b27c_o.jpg
2. Non Running https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8373/8362357598_6f93f9769f_o.jpg

Here is the query:

```
select COUNT(*) 
from 
  PlannedShift 
where 
  ShiftDate >= '1/14/13' 
  and ShiftDate <= '1/20/13' 
  and (ShiftType = 'F' or ShiftType = 'G')
  and JobID in 
  (
        select ID from Assignment where ID in 
        (
                   3893,3894,3897,3896,3898,3899,3900,3905,3907,3908,4514,4502,4512,4544,4501,4551,4519,4554,4523,4509,4504,4534,3975,3751,3755,3756,4025,3732,3913,27277,3921,4027,4016,3889,3735,3742,3736,3768,3803,3758,3752,3769,4532,4507,4505,4529,4517,4521,3748,3773,4518,3971,4015,3912,3966,3888,3919,3938,3865,3961,4010,3999,21368,4496,4524,4537,4513,3733,3793,3795,3882,3791,3890,3976,3954,3867,3832,4530,3857,3891,4555,3833,3892,4553,4540,3868,3858,3774,3782,4951,4998,3977,5033,5005,3834,3821,3869,3934,27308,3994,27337,27336,4516,4028,3926,4500,3805,4545,27315,27324,27325,3822,3933,3835,3806,3823,3849,3870,3814,3978,4497,3979,27339,3980,3981,4001,4002,3982,3995,3970,3729,3777,3743,3807,3850,3837,3825,3808,3872,3836,3895,3824,3871,4515,3941,3927,3967,4510,4538,3737,3996,3809,3844,4044,5016,8050,8052,8051,3887,3918,3937,3771,3960,3965,4024,3847,3820,3831,4009,3998,3962,3910,4013,27326,27311,27310,27281,27312,27282,27302,27305,3950,3810,4003,3757,3778,4029,3928,27299,27300,4550,4526,3779,3873,4030,27313,4528,3990,3922,3988,3731,3747,3932,3948,4004,4031,3929,4546,4032,4033,5002,4034,3987,3838,3826,3851,3989,4863,3759,3761,4527,4548,3914,3942,3983,3991,3968,4019,4035,4536,4543,27284,27276,3801,4522,3799,3874,3815,3754,3760,4005,4036,4525,4541,27309,27307,27278,27279,27280,27301,27327,3949,4037,4038,4039,4017,4511,4542,4508,3974,3885,3886,3856,3786,4533,3741,3972,3939,3734,3772,3750,3767,3963,4549,4011,4520,4026,4499,3881,3846,3843,3819,3866,4000,3848,3940,3740,3964,4018,3816,3813,3992,3875,3780,4040,3924,3973,5019,4041,3753,3763,3800,3749,3762,3945,3901,3951,3796,4023,4020,5031,8054,5027,4996,27283,3953,3802,3946,27314,3943,4006,3902,3903,3863,3859,3839,4535,3827,3852,3876,3860,3877,3765,3952,3904,27298,3920,3911,4014,4012,27306,27303,27304,3955,3853,3915,3985,3984,3883,3788,3744,4007,3861,3787,3797,5000,4552,4556,7959,3789,3745,3738,3764,3854,3840,3828,4021,4042,3956,3916,3906,4498,4506,3935,3841,3811,3829,3878,4927,4925,4547,4503,4531,3930,3879,3776,3783,3957,4898,4539,4907,3775,4854
        ) 
        and ID not in 
        (
              select distinct JobID from EmployeeShift where JobID in 
              (
                    3893,3894,3897,3896,3898,3899,3900,3905,3907,3908,4514,4502,4512,4544,4501,4551,4519,4554,4523,4509,4504,4534,3975,3751,3755,3756,4025,3732,3913,27277,3921,4027,4016,3889,3735,3742,3736,3768,3803,3758,3752,3769,4532,4507,4505,4529,4517,4521,3748,3773,4518,3971,4015,3912,3966,3888,3919,3938,3865,3961,4010,3999,21368,4496,4524,4537,4513,3733,3793,3795,3882,3791,3890,3976,3954,3867,3832,4530,3857,3891,4555,3833,3892,4553,4540,3868,3858,3774,3782,4951,4998,3977,5033,5005,3834,3821,3869,3934,27308,3994,27337,27336,4516,4028,3926,4500,3805,4545,27315,27324,27325,3822,3933,3835,3806,3823,3849,3870,3814,3978,4497,3979,27339,3980,3981,4001,4002,3982,3995,3970,3729,3777,3743,3807,3850,3837,3825,3808,3872,3836,3895,3824,3871,4515,3941,3927,3967,4510,4538,3737,3996,3809,3844,4044,5016,8050,8052,8051,3887,3918,3937,3771,3960,3965,4024,3847,3820,3831,4009,3998,3962,3910,4013,27326,27311,27310,27281,27312,27282,27302,27305,3950,3810,4003,3757,3778,4029,3928,27299,27300,4550,4526,3779,3873,4030,27313,4528,3990,3922,3988,3731,3747,3932,3948,4004,4031,3929,4546,4032,4033,5002,4034,3987,3838,3826,3851,3989,4863,3759,3761,4527,4548,3914,3942,3983,3991,3968,4019,4035,4536,4543,27284,27276,3801,4522,3799,3874,3815,3754,3760,4005,4036,4525,4541,27309,27307,27278,27279,27280,27301,27327,3949,4037,4038,4039,4017,4511,4542,4508,3974,3885,3886,3856,3786,4533,3741,3972,3939,3734,3772,3750,3767,3963,4549,4011,4520,4026,4499,3881,3846,3843,3819,3866,4000,3848,3940,3740,3964,4018,3816,3813,3992,3875,3780,4040,3924,3973,5019,4041,3753,3763,3800,3749,3762,3945,3901,3951,3796,4023,4020,5031,8054,5027,4996,27283,3953,3802,3946,27314,3943,4006,3902,3903,3863,3859,3839,4535,3827,3852,3876,3860,3877,3765,3952,3904,27298,3920,3911,4014,4012,27306,27303,27304,3955,3853,3915,3985,3984,3883,3788,3744,4007,3861,3787,3797,5000,4552,4556,7959,3789,3745,3738,3764,3854,3840,3828,4021,4042,3956,3916,3906,4498,4506,3935,3841,3811,3829,3878,4927,4925,4547,4503,4531,3930,3879,3776,3783,3957,4898,4539,4907,3775,4854
              ) 
              and ShiftTypeCode = 'S' and ShiftDate >= '1/14/13' and ShiftDate <= '1/20/13'
        ) 
        and TypeCode <> 'E'
  )
```

Comment: What do you mean not running?  Do you get an error?

Comment: No, it will continue forever. Or at least until i give up after 2 hours. The date range that works takes less than a second.

Comment: I also had an index with ShiftDate, ShiftCategoryID, and ShiftTypeCode, with the Included Column of JobID. I added the JobID to the index and that still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the row count estimates are way off for the "non Running" case. A nested loops join is usually used when the datasets involved are small. If that turns out to be a wrong assumption, nested loops can take a very long time.

Try to get an actual execution plan (let the query run over night) and save it as XML. then check where the actual row counts don't match the expected. Make sure your statistics are up to date on that table.

If you need more help, post the actual XML execution plan here.

More detail about the nested loops join algorithm you can find here: http://sqlity.net/en/1471/a-join-a-day-the-nested-loops-join/

Comment: Quite likely the [ascending date](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2011/03/22/statistics-row-estimations-and-the-ascending-date-column/) issue and the stats haven't been auto updated since data for that later time period was added.

Comment: Thank you, It was the ascending date issue.